# getting .o file not recognized while ld gives error 1 exit status

Tags: gcc, file-format

I'm compiling an app, and I need to use a file, and that file is lzss.o. It's for a file creator/extractor, so it needs this. When I run it, I get the error that the file extension isn't recognized, and LD gives me error 1 exit status.
If I need to include code from lzss.h, lzss.cpp, I can link it.

Here's what my GCC command looks like.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code and/or diagnostics. Also, if would help if you familiarized yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the output of `file lzss.o`?

Comment: The output is just "data". I don't know what's wrong with it, cause this same line of code only don't work on this PC. This PC has the same specs and everything. This happened on the old PC though, but the problem just went away.

Comment: For `ld` to be able to link it, this has to be an ELF relocatable file.